# Where can I find good Documentation on OpenXML for Word Document Processing?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

As I am new to OpenXML I am learning it at my own and get a basic knowledge about OpenXML but now I am willing to learn How to manipulate word document through C# code using OpenXML.

So please Suggest me good documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it at **MSDN**, this is `how to` series: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850833.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this sample from [codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/994905/Edit-Word-Documents-using-OpenXML-and-Csharp-Witho)

```
    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create
("D:\\test11.docx", DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
       {
           // Add a main document part.
           MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();

           // Create the document structure and add some text.
           mainPart.Document = new Document();
           Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
           Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
           Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());

           // String msg contains the text, "Hello, Word!"
           run.AppendChild(new Text("New text in document"));
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 1 of the ebook *Open XML - The Markup Explained* by Wouter van Vugt
 covers many details of WordprocessingML.  WordprocessingML is the OpenXML namespace that covers MS Word documents.  You can find a PDF copy of the book at this [OpenXMLDeveloper.org post](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2007/08/13/1970.aspx).  You should download a copy soon, the site hosting the ebook might be shutting down.